# bootstrap 4 nav. z-index in multinav

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4, z-index

I have a bootstrap 4 nav modified as a multi-flyout navigation.

html:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown IFSUB"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Reiseziele</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Europa <i class="fal fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Orient <i class="fal fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Afrika <i class="fal fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown-submenu IFSUB"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Asien/Ozeanien <i class="fal fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-2">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Butan</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">China</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Indien</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Indonesien</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Japan</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Kambodscha</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Laos</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Malaysia</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Mongolei</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Myanmar</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Nepal</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Neuseeland</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Russland</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Sri Lanka</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Thauland</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Tibet</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Turkmenistan</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Usbekiastan</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Vietnam</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Mittelamerika <i class="fal fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Südamerika <i class="fal fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Reisevarianten</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item NO"><a href="#" class="nav-link">So reisen wir</a></li>
</ul>

.nav-item {
        &:hover, &:focus, .active {
            .nav-link {
                background-color: red;
                color: white;
            }
        }
        .nav-link {
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            padding: .5rem .75rem;
            &:hover, &:focus, .active {
                background-color: red;
                color: white;
            }
        }
        &.dropdown {
            > .dropdown-menu {
                border: 0;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border-top-right-radius: 0;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
                box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
                .nav-item {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid darken(red,15%);
                    &:last-child {
                        border-bottom: 0;
                    }
                    .nav-link {
                        font-size: 1rem;
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        align-items: center;
                        padding: .75rem 1rem;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        background-color: inherit;
                        color: black;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                        &:hover, &:focus, .active {
                            background-color: inherit;
                            color: red;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            &:hover {
                > .dropdown-menu {
                    display: block;
                    border: 0;
                }
            }
        }
        &.dropdown-submenu {
            > .dropdown-menu {
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin-top: 0;
                margin-left: 0;
                border: 0;
                padding: 0 15px;
                border-top-left-radius: 0;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
                box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
                background-color: #efefef;
                .nav-item {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
                    &:last-child {
                        border-bottom: 0;
                    }
                }
                > .row {
                    flex-wrap: nowrap;
                }
                [class*="col-"] {
                    min-width: 10rem;
                    padding: 1.55rem 20px;
                }
            }
            &:hover {
                > .dropdown-menu {
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

scss:

```
.nav-item {
 &:hover, &:focus, .active {
  .nav-link {
   background-color: $WIE-default;
   color: $white;
  }
 }
 .nav-link {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
  &:hover, &:focus, .active {
   background-color: $WIE-default;
   color: $white;
  }
 }
 &.dropdown {
  > .dropdown-menu {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   border-top-right-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   .nav-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid darken($mainnav-dropdown-submenu,15%);
    &:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0;
    }
    .nav-link {
     font-size: 1rem;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     padding: .75rem 1rem;
     font-weight: normal;
     background-color: inherit;
     color: $black;
     white-space: nowrap;
     &:hover, &:focus, .active {
      background-color: inherit;
      color: $WIE-default;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  &:hover {
   > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
   }
  }
 }
 &.dropdown-submenu {
  > .dropdown-menu {
   top: 0;
   left: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   border: 0;
   padding: 0 15px;
   border-top-left-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   background-color: $mainnav-dropdown-submenu;
   .nav-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    &:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0;
    }
   }
   > .row {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
   }
   [class*="col-"] {
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: 1.55rem 20px;
   }
  }
  &:hover {
   > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

If you hover over 'Reiseziele' the first flyout shows, then hover over 'Asien/Ozeanien' the second flyout shows. Everything works fine.

I now want the second flyout behind the first flyout. The shadow of the first flyout (right side) should overlap the second flyout at the moment it is otherwise.

At the moment:
shadow-box1|box1|shadow-box2|box2|shadow-box2

I want:
shadow-box1|box1|shadow-box1|box2|shadow-box2

I have tried almost everything with z-index, but I don't get it.

[Here a codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JByLQr)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am able to interpret you correctly, you want your box-shadow of box1 to be evident rather than the box2 shadow. To make box1-shadow to be evident, please consider following points:

- There has to be some space between box1 and box2 (margin-left of box2 == shadow width).
- Box2 shadow should be adjusted to make it evident on right side of box not on left side, something like (https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow).

Please try to make above changes, and see if your problem is solved.